# Deprecation in navigationOptions: headerLeft: <SomeElement /> will be removed in a future version

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I get this error when running my app from terminal

```
Deprecation in navigationOptions: headerLeft: <SomeElement /> will be removed in a future version
```

but if I search my project I get 0 results for `headerLeft`.

How can this be?

I'm using react-native-router-flux

Answer (score 0):

try headerShown: false or if it doesnt work means that there is a headerLeft code inside the package and they didnt update their package.

Comment: Read my question again. There is no headerLeft in my code

Comment: I dont see headerShown either

Comment: im telling you to add headerShown: false on your code

Comment: if your using vscode try global searching headerleft